# Как сделать валидный SSL-сертификат для HTTPS-соединения в локальной сети?

Tags: ssl, https, push-уведомления, сертификат, локальная-сеть

> Под локальной сетью понимается действительно сеть из множества машин,
> а не *localhost*.
>
> Под валидным сертификатом понимается, что при переходе на локальный
> сайт по HTTPS-протоколу всё сразу будет хорошо - без вопросов,
> доверять ли сертификату, и без предварительной установки этого
> сертификата или центра сертификации на все машины сети, т.к. их >3к.

Итак, есть локальная сеть, в ней сервер на Apache2, к которому привязан внутренний домен.

**IP внутри сети:** *10.0.1.187*

**Домен:** *http://news/* (можно изменить на любой)

Необходимо реализовать полностью валидный переход на *https://news/*

Это нужно для PUSH-уведомлений, т.к. по незащищённому соединению они отказываются работать.

Ни самоподписанный сертификат через **openssl**, ни собственный центр сертификации через **mkcert** мне не подходят, т.к. они требуют установки на машины, которых больше 3 тысяч.

Т.е. мне нужно как-то получить сертификат для домена *news*, подписанный реальным центром сертификации, например, **Let's Encrypt**, которому все браузеры в сети уже доверяют.

Есть ли какой-то способ это сделать?

Comment: выходов много: 1. взломать инфраструктуру letsencrypt, 2. купить компанию letsencrypt. 3. устроиться туда ведущим специалистом по безопасности. 4. подкупить ведущего специалиста по безопасности. 5. дождаться пока квантовые компьютеры дорастут до взлома использующихся ключей. 6. ещё множество вариантов.

Comment: Сделать полноценный домен (`news.mycompany.com`)

Comment: Хотя проблема установить серт на 3000 машин непонятна. При таком количестве машин уже должно быть централизованное управление этим зоопарком (active directory и т.п.)

Comment: @AlexeyTen это ж не решение задачи. вот ещё самый очевидный вариант я забыл упомянуть: выкупить у владельцев gtld `news`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin почему? *Домен [...] (**можно изменить на любой**)*

Comment: заведи реальный сайт `news.haljavahosting.com`, получи у letsencrypt для него сертификат, создай в локальной сети сайт с таким же именем, в DNS локальной сети резолвь его в 10.0.1.187.  Те, у кого включен DoH, придут к тебе с жалобами )))